# What is this weird PING response I got?

Tags: networking, macos, router, ping

I added a static route on my router to an address that is on a different subnet than the rest of my computers.  It works fine, but when I ping it, I get the following response from the `ping` command that I've never seen before:

```
64 bytes from 10.11.12.13: icmp_seq=0 ttl=127 time=1.527 ms
92 bytes from 10.0.0.1: Redirect Host(New addr: 10.0.0.254)
Vr HL TOS  Len   ID Flg  off TTL Pro  cks      Src      Dst
 4  5  00 0054 bf4c   0 0000  3f  01 9c43 10.0.0.2  10.11.12.13
```

I'm pinging this from a Mac, BTW.

My router is 10.0.0.1. The host in question has 2 NICs in it.  One is 10.11.12.13, and the other is a DHCP reservation on my router with an address of 10.0.0.254 (which explains the redirect address).

Obviously this is because of the static route (duh), but what the heck is this response?? I've never seen the `ping` command give a response like that before.

Comment: Maybe useful: [Why do ICMP Redirect Host happen?](https://serverfault.com/a/402047 "Why do ICMP Redirect Host happen?")

Answer (score 8):

Your router sent you an ICMP Redirect message in response to your ICMP Echo Request because the host you are trying to reach is on the same LAN as you, but your network stack had addressed your packet to the router’s MAC address (because the destination IP address was off-subnet and your router was your default route). So the router’s saying “hey, that guy’s on the same LAN as you. Talk to him directly and stop burdening me to relay traffic you should be sending directly”. The ping command displayed the content of that ICMP Redirect.

If you tried to make a TCP connection to the same IP address, you’d get an equivalent ICMP Redirect, but your network stack would probably just handle it rather than show it to you. The only reason the ping command shows it to you is because the ping command is a network diagnostic tool, so it figures you’d be interested in this kind of detail.

Comment: Is there a better way to do it? Without the static route I can't ping the address at all. Also, what does the data in all those columns mean?

Comment: @WesSayeed A better way to do what? Tell me your goal in adding an off- subnet IP address that host. I can’t advise you unless I understand you goals and constraints. Otherwise my advice is to delete the 10.11.12.13 address since it seems superfluous if it’s already reachable at 10.0.0.254.

Comment: I'm building a virtual lab to explore networking concepts, and this sort of thing is exactly what I'm wanting to get out of it. All the VM NICs are set to host only on a 10.11.12.x subnet so they can't communicate with the outside world except through the gateway VM. That VM has 2 NICs, 1 static (10.11.12.13), and the other bridged to my router (10.0.0.254). This all works fine if I set the external NIC to "shared", but then I'm double-NATed, and I also intend to set up a 2nd virt lab on a different physical PC. I'm going to need to route between them without NATing all over the place.